# Function being called several times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following function which calls another one called 'change_name(event, name)'. Turns out 'change_name' is called more than just one time? The variables it uses have mixed values.

```
function input_name(event, name) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    name.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    window.localStorage.removeItem("oldname");
    window.localStorage.setItem("oldname", name.value);
    $(this).click( function()
    { 

    change_name(event, name); } );

    $(name).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            change_name(event, name);
        }
    }); 
}


 function change_name(event, element) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      var name_input = element;
      var name = name_input.value;
      var oldname = window.localStorage.getItem("oldname");
    // new_name.innerHTML = name;
     console.log("Nombre viejo: " + oldname);
     console.log("Nombre nuevo: " + name);

 }
```

input_name function is an attribute of an element

```
 input.setAttribute("onclick", "input_name(event, this);");
```

Why are my values getting mixed up?? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `input_name`?

Comment: @Nathan It's an onclick function    (just updated it above)

Comment: Why are you adding a new click handler every time?

Comment: You're attaching multiple click and keydown listeners to the input

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a new `click` and `keydown` event on every click of `input`. These events need to be added outside of the click event.

```
// on click, input_name is called
input.setAttribute("onclick", "input_name(event, this);");

// this function is called on every click of input
function input_name(event, name) {

  // new events are added on every click
  $(this).click(function() {/* ? */});
  $(name).keydown(function(event) {/* ? */}); 
}
```

So do something like this instead:

```
// on click, input_name is called
input.setAttribute("onclick", "input_name(event, this);");

// events are added once
$(input).click(function() {/* ? */});
$(input).keydown(function(event) {/* ? */}); 

// this function is called on every click of input
function input_name(event, name) {
  /* ? */
}
```

also look into why you are using `$().click` to create an onclick and also `input.setAttribute("onclick", ...)` Since you have jQuery, prefer using `$().click` over setting the attribute.